# Is this part a 1.1A 0805 self-recovery fuse?

Tags: surface-mount, fuses

I bought this online, It should be 1.1A 0805, but is it ? The pakage size is correct, Its 0805 but the value, I have doubts! [image]

Comment: I don't think we could instill any more trust in this than your electronics distributor should already inspire … in other words, if you can't trust whoever sells you components to deliver what you order, you chose the wrong vendor.

Comment: As it's meant to be a self recovering fuse, that means you can test it non-destructively.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Major distributors do make mistakes, and with cut tape it's hard to verify even the markings. The percentage should be very low for a good distributor (maybe 1 in 1000 or lower), but it's never zero, and of course there should be a manufacturer's datasheet to compare. It's easier with reels because there's always good markings on the reel.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm assuming a distributor would aim lower - these service cases and the loss of time for the customer could be very dangerous for the distributor's bottom line. But that level is excellent for illustration: so, you would expect this to be 99.9% likely to be the right component with your distributors; taking it to strangers on the internet should not be able at all to increase certainty at a significant level, so it could only be used to falsify. But how hard could strangers on the internet prove this to be something else when number of contacts and form factor match specs?

Comment: @MarcusMüller We detected measurable (but reasonably low) errors with Digikey, for example, it's not a theoretical comment. There could be additional ones that were not detected. Unless you do incoming testing (and not just checking off the markings the distributor put on the bag, which are almost guaranteed to match the order) it's hard to be sure. Of course there's significant additional risks if OP is dealing with eBay or such like. Parts could be fallouts or worse.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that's undisputably true. Didn't realize you had your own studies on that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly possible. For example, it could be a Shenzhen JinRui [JK-SMD0805-110-6](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_Jinrui-Electronic-Materials-Co--JK-SMD0805-035_C369149.pdf).
[image]

Note that a 1A part would have exactly the same markings. They're all over the place with various manufacturers' markings anyway. Photo from lcsc:

[image]